# how to redirect url in flask depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I want to redirect the URL when the variable search_done is true, but until then I want the loading file to show but i can't manage to do so.

I've tried doing all sorts of variable passing to html but because the variable changes during the run of the loading file the variable won't be true.

The URL changes to the loading file when a search button is clicked.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    global search_done
    global songs
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_request = request.form.getlist('search[]')
        songs=[]
        data=search_api(search_request)
        search_done=False
        if data!=None:
            for hit in data:
                songs.append(Song(hit['result']['full_title'],hit['result']['primary_artist']['name'],hit['result']['url'],hit['result']['song_art_image_thumbnail_url']))
            for i in songs:
                print(i)
            search_done=True
    return render_template('layout.html')

@app.route("/result")
def result():
    global songs
    return render_template("result.html",songs=songs)

@app.route("/loading")
def load():
    global search_done  
    while not search_done:
        return render_template("loading.html")                      
    return redirect(url_for('result'))
```

I want the url to redirect to 'result' but it just stays as the loading page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in the way you're thinking. In short, the most simple way to get there is by adding some Javascript to the page (ajax), and poll your server to find when the variable changes. There are a few things to consider:

1. How will you store the variable? [Session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions) is an option for non-important, small values. Otherwise a [DB](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/) may be necessary for large data sets, or a [background worker](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) may be necessary for long running processes.
2. Getting the value back into the view can be done using ajax (e.g. [jquery `$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) and a [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function with javascript. This should call a new route in your app that retrieves the value from the storage method you're using.
3. Going fully async and looking at [Sockets](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/) (for example) will give you the ability to create more 'live' views, where your app view can listen for events and update without reloading. This does change how your app is run however.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how can I ask the server repetitively about the variable?

Comment: And how can I use the variable when it's not on the same page anymore?

Comment: This is what I've explained, point 2 refers to how you would call the server using the `setTimeout` function. Point 1 is how you would store the variable so that you can use it between views (pages).